# photoshop cs6 black screen flickering issues

Tags: windows-10, cpu, adobe-photoshop, intel-graphics, intel-core-i7

I have a [intel core i7 2600](http://ark.intel.com/products/52213/Intel-Core-i7-2600-Processor-8M-Cache-up-to-3_80-GHz). My screen resolution is 1920x1080 @ 60Hz via vga port. Motherboard [Gigabyte H61M-S2P-B3](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=3992#ov). Ram 1x Dynet 4GB @ 1333MHz and 1x Corsair 2GB @ 1333MHz. Total 6GB of Ram. I dont have any dedicated graphics card. So I use built in one. But it seems my photoshop struggles to work With my processor Built in graphics. It only take 5 to 10 second to open and Saving a big photo is also fast (There is no problem with Disk speed). But I have some problem with screen flickering. I always work on 8 bit/channel and RGB or CMYK color(I didn't use 16 bit or 32 bit). I don't know what is 8bit, 16bit and 32 bit channel on photoshop. I am designing a 1600 by 3000 pixel template. With 8 bit RGB color. I have searched online for "photoshop cs6 black screen flickering issues" and found some solution. one of them say just change the image mode 8 bit to 32 bit from the image menu. like this:

[image: snapshot]

the problem is I have faced some problem to follow the solution. First, when I click on 32bit/Channel photoshop tells me to merge all the layers. Like this:

[image: pop up]

But I can't do this because I need layers as they are now. So I clicked on "Don't Merge" button and then photoshop tell me to Flatten visible layers and discard hidden layers. Like this:

[image: Flatten]

I Don't want to make layers flat and discard hidden layers. So I pressed cancel.

Any solution?

Answer (score -1):

For all those people who face this error please find below the easiest solution for this error.

1. First of all click on the Catalyst Control Center.
2. Now click on ‘3D Application Settings’.
3. All you have to do is change the ‘Wait for Vertical Refresh’ option to ‘On, unless application specifies’.

If you are not able to fix the issue using the steps given above and wanna try some other effective methods visit : [Windows 8 and Photoshop CS6 Black Screen Flickering](http://www.dragdigital.com/windows-8-and-photoshop-cs6-black-screen-flickering/)

Comment: You should describe those effective methods in the body of your answer.